# Can I make my discord bot send a message to all servers that has the bot added to it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that periodically checks some data in a database and if there is an update it outputs something to the channel. So I set a function that will run every hour.

```py
async def check_new():
    general_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Update!",
        color=0xff0000,
        description=''
    )
    while True:
        change = check_change()
        if change:
            await general_channel.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

    bot.loop.create_task(check_new())
```

The issue comes when the bot is added to multiple servers where the message only gets sent to a specific to a specific `channel_id` so messages get sent only to my server channel. Essentially I am sending a notification to only my channel, how can I send one to every channel that has my bot, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of guilds your bot is in, with `bot.guilds`

```py
   if change:
      guilds = bot.guilds()
      for guild in guilds:
         channels = guild.channels #get all channels
         for channel in channels: 
            try:
               await channel.send(embed=embed)
               break
            except:
               print('unable to send in', channel, guild)
```

Although you can do this and it will work fine, I wouldn't recommend doing it as the bot may send the `update` in random channels. I suggest you ask the users to set a `bot updates` channel, so you can store it in a database and use it to send updates.

### References:

- [bot.guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)
- [guild.channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels)

Comment: I didn't think of storing channel ids in a database so that works thanks! I modified my 
bot to to add the channel_id to the database so when an update happens, the channel_id gets passed back and the bot knows how to send it.

Comment: Great! Looks like you figured that out on your own